# How to retrieve an objects id using jquery

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I have the following 2 links which are formed in a ruby rails .each do block:

```
<%= link_to "Reply", '#', class: 'reply-link', id: "reply-#{sender}" %>
<%= link_to "Resolved", '#', class: 'complete-link', id: "resolved-#{sender}" %>
```

I want to be able to do something like this but I'm not sure how to extract the rails record id (#{sender}) in the ajax post.

```
$('.reply-link').click(function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/messages/complete?sender='+$(this).attr("id")
 });
});
```

The `$(this).attr("id")` above obviously returns `reply-1` instead of `1`

Comment: `link_to "Reply", '#', class: 'reply-link', id: "reply-#{sender}"` you're setting the id to "reply-number"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a data-* attribute as well, if it fits your needs:

```
<%= link_to "Reply", '#', class: 'reply-link', data: { id: sender } %>
<%= link_to "Resolved", '#', class: 'complete-link', data: { id: sender } %>
```

You can then use

```
$('.reply-link').data('id')
$('.resolved-link').data('id')
```

which is cleaner instead of putting "reply-" and "resolved-" strings in the id attribute and then having to do string manipulations.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the correct id, if you need number then need to remove string `reply-` from the id.

```
$(this).attr("id").replace("reply-", "");
```

Comment: Thanks @RUJordan, so nice of you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `split` method to get your `id` like so:

`$(this).attr("id").split("-")[1];`

But a cleaner and better solution would be to go for the `data` attribute. In this case, you would store the `id` like this:

`<%= link_to "Reply", '#', class: 'reply-link', data-id: sender %>`

You can retrieve this with the `data` method:

`var id = $(this).data("id");`

An added advantage of this is the fact that `data` attributes get cached by `JQuery`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).attr("id")
```

is returning correct id `"reply-1"` for the element. But you need number out of that id attribute, so do the following:--

```
$(this).attr("id").split("-")[1]
```

Answer (score -1):

try this,

```
$('.reply-link').click(function(event) {
 event.preventDefault();
  $.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '/messages/complete?sender='+$(this).attr("id").split("-")[1]
 });
});
```

Comment: $(this).attr("id").split("reply-")[1] will give you the id e.g: for "reply-1" it will give you "1".

Comment: Yes you are right. It will work. But its not the ideal usage of the `split` function.